# Trouble setting ArrayAdapter Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am using a navigation drawer as the main layout for my app (comes builtin with new ADT March update). I am trying to set the arrayadapter as follows:

```
String[] items = new String[]{getString(R.string.home), getString(R.string.map),      getString(R.string.update), getString(R.string.settings)};
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            R.layout.list_view,
            R.id.list_item,
            items
            ));
```

/res/layout/list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:singleLine="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

/res/layout/list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:background="#000000" />
```

My goal is trying to replace the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` `android.R.id.text1` that the app base comes with by default.

**EDIT**

The error I get is:

```
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533): Process: com.unofficiallycoded.howsthewait, PID: 28533
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to     invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null  object reference
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-11 18:27:32.516: E/AndroidRuntime(28533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Answer (score 1):

the first resource id should be the list item one I guess.

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                R.id.list_item,
                items                ));
```

Comment: That didn't work. Theres an error with the XML parser when I do that, I posted my full stack trace.

Comment: Guess the android:id="@+id/list_item" has to be the android.R.id.text1 it's looking for so android:id="@+id/text1" ?